# Detection pay or free phone call (programmatically)

Tags: android, phone-call

When we call on the cost number, it's time conversation starts and is shown. When we call the number for customer service (our telephone company), or we do not have money in account phone, time the conversation does not start, is not shown.

I call so:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent1.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: Could you get the country + area code of a number, then simply compare that against known numbers that cost or not?

Comment: Given that this is a function of your network, your tariff and the recipient, it's unlikely that you'll be able to determine this programmatically.

Comment: I tested on my phone Samsung GT-S7562 (Android 4.0.4, kernel 3.0.8) and phone dialer that somehow recognizes (call time counter starts or not). So I think that this should be solved programmatically.